# Como cambiar cada clase del icono mediante un request en ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

Buenas estoy trabajando en una aplicacion en net core 5
Este es el codigo de mi funcion en el controlador:

```
var likesCancion = (from likesCanc in _context.table
                               where likesCanc.SongId == idCancion && likesCanc.UserId == idUser
                               select likesCanc.Likes).FirstOrDefault();

            if (likesCancion == 1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
```

Y tengo este div que contiene un i tag con los datos mostrados a continuación:

```
<div class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                            <i class="far fa-heart" id="heart"  data-idAudio = @song.Id>
                                <span class="badge"  >@song.Likes</span>
                            </i>
                        </div>
```

El atributo **data-idAudio** es el id de la cancion que viene desde la base de datos

Hice un request en ajax haciendole un loop al i tag con id #heart y le mande al contolador la informacion para q si se cumplen los requisitos el controlador solo envia 1 o 0:

```
const iconosCorazon = document.querySelectorAll('#heart');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                        let idUser = $('#inputidUsuario').val();

                            function makeRequest(i) 
                            {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "checkHeart",
                                    data: { idCancion: i, idUser: idUser },
                                    dataType: "text",
                                    success: function (msg) {
                                        console.log(msg);
                                        **if (msg == 1) {
                                            $('.fa-heart').removeClass("far text-dark");
                                            $('.fa-heart').addClass("fa text-danger");
                                        }
                                        else
                                        { 
                                            $('.fa-heart').removeClass("fa text-danger");
                                            $('.fa-heart').addClass("far fa-heart");
                                        }**
                                    },
                                    error: function (req, status, error) {
                                        console.log(msg);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            for (var i=0;i<iconosCorazon.length;i++) {
                                let idCancion = iconosCorazon[i].getAttribute('data-idAudio');
                                makeRequest(idCancion);
                               
                            }
```

Lo que sucede es que el ajax al ser asincrono se ejecutan todos los llamados del loop a la vez y como resultado me cambia todos los elementos del i tag al ultimo valor resultante del ajax
Mi pregunta es como se podría cambiar la clase del i tag en dependencia del resultado que me envia el for loop uno a uno.
ej: If result == 1 cambia el color del icono a rojo, if result == 0 cambia el color del icono a otro color.

Comment: Los ID se supone que deben de ser únicos, nunca va a buscar más de uno... porque no debería haber más de uno :) Si quieres anotar varios elementos con un nombre común, debes usar una clase, no una ID. Primero que nada, arregla el problema de los ID únicos. Luego, en la respuesta de ajax necesitas tener también el `data-idAudio` para poder identificar a qué elemento corresponde la llamada (pásalo como parámetro al método `makeRequest`!), entonces podrás seleccionar el elemento correspondiente y editarlo. O directamente pasa el elemento entero :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Ya en la parte del `document.querySelectorAll `  lo cambie para que seleccionara por clase. De hecho se lo tengo que enviar pq es uno de los datos que tengo que pasar a la función en el controlador. Me causa una duda tu respuesta tambien ya que el elemento **data-idAudio** ya yo se lo paso al método **makeRequest**. Pero mi problema aún sigue siendo el success del ajax que siempre me ejecuta(como debe funcionar) el ultimo elemento y yo quiero que a cada tag le cambie su class según el resultado

Comment: Claro que se lo aplica a todos... porque buscas así: `$('.fa-heart')`. Eso está buscando todos los elementos que tengan esa clase. En vez de eso deberías buscar el elemento que tiene el `data-idAudio` específico que necesitas! Algo así: `$('*[data-idAudio=i]')`